# Prisma Psql Argument: Invalid value provided

Tags: psql, prisma

Good day,

Psql beginner here, I tried this request

[image]

In this endpoint

[image]

With this model

[image]

But when doing the request it says. **Argument `images`: Invalid value provided. Expected ImageCreateNestedManyWithoutUploadInput or ImageUncheckedCreateNestedManyWithoutUploadInput, provided (Object, Object)**

All I want to see is for every upload has many images in it that is why Upload model has images[]. I don't know if my models connection is correct.

Please enlighten me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer now. I images[] must have create

```
const payload = {
 images: {
  create: images,
  ...
}}
```

For more info https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model